# Specific static file not load in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

My S3 Dir

`My Bucket Name > static > frontend > images > [hash-name].png`

`My Bucket Name > static > frontend > main.js`

My nginx project.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.compute.amazonaws.com *.***.com;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    # Buffer
    client_body_buffer_size 4096K;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
       uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/****.sock;
       include     uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias https://****.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias https://****.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/media/;
    }
}
```

settings.py

```
#.config_secret/settings_common.json = AWS Key, info
CONFIG_SECRET_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, '.config_secret')
CONFIG_SETTINGS_COMMON_FILE = os.path.join(CONFIG_SECRET_DIR, 'settings_common.json')

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, '.static_root')

MEDIA_URL =  '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

# S3 Storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = '****.storages.MediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = '****.storages.StaticStorage'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'

# AWS Access
config_secret = json.loads(open(CONFIG_SETTINGS_COMMON_FILE).read())
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config_secret['aws']['access_key_id']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config_secret['aws']['secret_access_key']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config_secret['aws']['s3_bucket_name']
```

main.js
[image]
image.png
[image]
The structure of the project is as follows.
main.js is normally taken by s3 when confirmed by the developer tool.
However, files in the image folder are trying to get from a common address, not s3, resulting in a 404 error.
What should I do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

webpack.config.js

```
output : {
   publicPath: "https://****.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/static/frontend/"
}
```

I'm Fool